# Matplotlib - 3D plotting - Points are being defaulted to circles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get do a 3D scatter plot, but the only markers that seems to work are so large that they start overlapping. I would like to just use `'.'` or `','`, but I always get bumped to using `'o'`. I could live with those if `markersize` would work in 3D plots. Is there a way around this?

Comment: When you're plotting in 3D, the size of the marker is changed by saying `s =`.  For future reference, color is `c =`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Types of markers

For `scatter`, `'.'` is for point markers and `','` is for pixel markers. When I attempt to use them, however, I get a `ValueError` claiming they do not exist, but that is likely due to using matplotlib v1.0.1; the [changelog for v1.1.x](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/api_changes.html#changes-in-1-1-x) includes a comment on markers:

> There is now a common set of markers for all plotting functions. Previously, some markers existed only for `scatter()` or just for `plot()`. This is now no longer the case.

There is a table of the markers available for `scatter` in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) that you can try out. There is also an [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html) in the gallery with a scatter plot using different markers.

### Marker size

Marker size is also controllable in `scatter`, either with a scalar argument or an array to specify the size for each point. Take a look at the `s` formal parameter in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am sorta bound to using 1.0.1, so I seem to be stuck at the moment.

Comment: @madtowneast v1.0.1 still has markers other than `'o'` for `scatter`, just not the same set, or as many, as `plot`. My documentation lists `'s'`, `'o'`, `'^'`, `'>'`, `'v'`, `'<`', `'d'`, `'p'`, `'h'`, `'8'`, `'+'`, and `'x'`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was just looking for a point or pixel rather because I have a lot of points (10^6). I used s=1, which is nearly the equivalent of a point.